# Async task - not clear re called methods

Tags: android

I have a a service class which includes an Async task.   In the doInBackground and onPostExecute I call some methods which are in the service class but outside the Async task.  When these methods get called will they still be in the thread created by the Async task and therefore not interfering with the main UI.

To illustrate my lack of understanding a bit more should I try to get almost everything that the service class does into the Async task.   For example the service starts up as the result of an alarm and in the onStartCommand sets a repeating alarm  (this is as Reto Meire's Earthquake example)and creates a database.   Would it make sense to move the code for these two operations into the onPreExecute part of the Async task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do that.. make sure that the method which you want to run in background is called from `doInBavkground()`.. rest you can put in `postExecute`.... the snippet which you want to run after the backGround task should be in `PostExecute()`. If You call methods from `doInBackground()` they still run on background thread.. does't matter where they are.. and if you call it from `onPostExecute()` then it will run on other thread which ofcourse can make changes in your display.. just like showing dialog etc...

Answer (score 0):

You should always offload as much work as possible to background threads/tasks. Something like database creation should be done in the `doInBackground` method. The `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` methods run on the UI thread and are generally used to inform the user of background activity (e.g. using a `ProgressDialog`).

From experience, I also suggest **not** using a background service if you can get away with it. If you use one, you should know how to clean it up properly since users generally get annoyed with an application running in the background.

Comment: @Che Is the service as effective at not blocking as Async?   I based this model on Reto Meir's Earthquake sample and I thought I had read on here that running a service did not reduce the need to use Async.  I am confused and would appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: Services run on the main thread - you need to spawn an AsyncTask still. Deleted previous comment to avoid confusion. Still suggest *avoiding* Services.